# Objective C - XIB load in NSView

Tags: macos, load, xib, nsview

I'm new to Objective C coding and the MVC concept gives me some pain. My goal is to develop a Mac Application. I was able to create a .xib for the main window. It starts well.
My main NSWindow has its main NSView. In this NSView, I put 3 subwiews (using Interface Builder). What I want is to change the content of the 2nd subview (by loading the content from another XIB file, called SubWindow1.xib) when I click on a button placed in the 1st subview.

I'm able to catch the click and tried some "xib loading" code but it doesn't work (the content never appears in my 2nd subview).

What I did is:

- put the NSButton (on the 1st subview)
- put a NSObject on Interface Builder (class renamed CtMainWindow, "Ct" for Controler)
- link the IBAction (changeToSubWindow1) and IBOutlet (vSubView2 which is my 2nd subview)
- create the CtMainWindow class, create a VwSubWindow1 class (which extends NSView)

In changeToSubWindow1(), I wrote:

```
VwSubWindow1 * vProfile = [[VwSubWindow1 alloc] initWithFrame:vSubView2.bounds];
[vProfile loadXib];
[vProfile.superview addSubview:vProfile];
```

The loadXib() function does:

```
NSNib * nib = [[NSNib alloc] initWithNibNamed:[self @"SubWindow1"] bundle:nil];  //@"SubWindow1" is the name of the expected loaded xib without .xib extention
[nib instantiateWithOwner:self topLevelObjects:nil];
```

And Voila. I was hoping that loading the sub xib in a view, and putting that view in my 2nd subview, it would appear.

I also tried to put only the following code in changeToSubWindow1()

```
VwSubWindow1 * vProfile = [[VwSubWindow1 alloc] initWithFrame:vSubView2.bounds];
[vProfile loadSubWindow];
```

The loadSubWindow() function does:

```
[NSBundle loadNibNamed:@"SubWindow1" owner:self];
```

Without more success.

I already read lots of threads from stackoverflow and tried lots of solutions but none of them worked for me.

Can anyone give me the hint I need in order to load and display the Xib in a subview ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For the record, I put a "Hello" at the beginning of my message but it doesn't display, event if I edit my message

Answer (score 0):

you can try this method

you can put 3 xib files and 3 windows. connect each window

```
self.packages = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.window1.contentView addSubview:self.vc.view];
self.packages.view.frame = ((NSView*)self.window1.contentView).bounds;
[window1 makeKeyAndOrderFront:NSApp];
```